# how to display table value from another controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

> ```
> I have one CompanyConroller connect with companies table.
> ```
>
> how can i get companies table value via calling from SubadminController?

Answer (score 1):

You can get companies table value by calling SubadminController by giving this relation in Subadmin model

```
var $belongsTo = array("Company");
```

or

```
  var $hasMany = array("Company");
```